# may a subdomain can contain another subdomain in URL?

Tags: web

I just wanted to ask if

```
www.videos.example.com
```

is a valid subdomain name?

Comment: Yes it is a valid subdomain.

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: As www is also a sub domain

Answer (score 0):

```
You.can.go.as.deep.as.you.want.example.com.
```

1) This is mostly dependent on your DNS - usually, your hosting company manages this; also, if you have a wildcard 3rd-level domain `(*.example.com)`, then any domain name under `example.com` will point to the same host. So, it is possible and works in 90% of the cases.

2) It doesn't matter, really - it all depends on #3

3) If you configure them for different docroots, they will; else they won't.

4) Check the Host: header - there you'll see what the domain is (with PHP, this data would be in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`), and you can implement some switching logic in your code.